# Nested table Microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to create a nested table inside a table. any idea how I can achieve this? please check attached image

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't a nested table.

The creator of that table has most likely merged the Activity, Predecessor, and Time Estimates cells.

The table is not 5x5 cells, but 5x6.

To make this exact table design create a 5x6 cell table.

Then starting in the upper-left corner, highlight the the top two cells of the first column, right-click and select Merge.

Repeat this for the top two cells in the 2nd column as well.

Next, highlight the top cells in the 3rd, 4th, and 5th columns, right-click and select Merge.

You will now have a table that looks exactly like this one.

I recommend you spend some time reading up on working with Tables in Microsoft Word. There should be plenty of documentation for this in basic Office literature.